# jQuery with First selector is slower than without?

Tags: jquery

http://jsperf.com/dfgdfg33355

I have table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="data"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

 $(".a").parent("td").find(".data").html('1');

vs

$(".a").parent("td").find(".data:first").html('1');
```

when i press on the div with class `.a` - go to the first `td` above , and find the div with  class `.data` and put there a value.

my test was :

search for `.data` and put value

vs

search for **first** `.data` and put value

However it seems that if im not spcifieing first , it is faster.

how can it be ?

Comment: What do you selectors look like (in code)?

Comment: From the [`:first` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/): Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use pseudo selectors in jQuery you create the overhead of having to do work on that string to parse the selector. It is better to use the function equivelent rather than pseudo selectors.

Here is an updated version of your jsperf to show that using functions is a lot faster: http://jsperf.com/dfgdfg33355/2

Also if you check-out the above jsperf you will see that using `.next()` is the fastest method of DOM traversal in this situation.

Comment: I cant use next since i dont know if its pure next element.  - so i access the wrapper and then find inside. anyway - i took your answer with .eq(0) which is the fastest for what i need `$(".a").parent("td").find(".data").eq(0).html('1');`

Comment: If you can use `.nextAll('.data')` or `.siblings('.data')` that would be advisable, notice that `.siblings()` performed fast in the jsperf.

Comment: we can have a prblem if it is on table - so there is no siblings accept tr and td......

Answer (score 0):

This is because `:first` forces jQuery to perform one more operation than without.  Once it gets a list of `.data` in the first example "a" it simply operates on that list to set the html contents to `1`.  In the second example "sss" it has to do the same thing but also get the first element in the list.  It just so happens that in your example there is only one item in that list.

If you edit your html to have multiple `<div class="data"></div>` you should see a different result.

Comment: Using a string pseudo-selector like `:first` is also slow because it is a string that has to be worked on.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML structure is (and will be) like this you should use .next()

See http://jsperf.com/dfgdfg33355/3